# Intersection of 2 high dimensional balls

Tags: geometry

I am working in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I have a large ball radius $2 \delta \sqrt{n}$. Centered on the boundary of this ball, I have a smaller ball radius $\delta$. What is the probability that a uniformly selected point in the small $\delta$ ball will end up in the $2 \delta \sqrt{n}$ ball?

It should be "easy" to see that it's at least 1/4, but I can't.

Comment: Do we know anything about $n$?  Could it be $n=1$?

Comment: @GregoryGrant:  For $n=1$ the probability is $1/2$, no problem.

Comment: My probability isn't great -- but does this just come down to the fraction of the volume of smaller ball inside the larger ball to its total volume?

Comment: @Bye_World Yes that's another way of saying it. The reason I said probability was to avoid a constant factor.

Comment: I asked the professor today and he said just because it's "easy" doesn't mean it will take less than a week. He said it might just be large computation involving integrals and maybe there's no intuitive way to see it.